# Need help in jquery object error message

Tags: javascript, jquery

IE is showing below error message

> Object doesn't support property or method 'poshytip'

Code:

```
$('.demo-basic').poshytip();
$('.ec-tip-yellow').poshytip();
$('.ec-tip-yellowsimple').poshytip({
  className: 'tip-yellowsimple',
  showTimeout: 1,
  alignTo: 'target',
  alignX: 'center',
  offsetY: 5,
  allowTipHover: false
});
```

Comment: _error message with PHP_? This looks more like jQuery to me.

Comment: Please use correct tags, PHP has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: Three options: 1. You're not loading the poshytip plugin. 2. You're using the wrong URL to load the plugin. 3. You're loading the plugin before jQuery, not after (which is the correct order to do it in).

Comment: What version of IE and jQuery are you using? And is it working in other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

It is mostly that because of you forgot to include the poshytip JS file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/jquery.poshytip.js"></script>
```

Check if you have added that! If you are getting this issue only in IE, then you have to check your conditional comments:

```
<!--[IF IE]>
  Only IE can parse this. Make sure you include the script here!
<![ENDIF]-->
```

My best guess is that you are including the script inside a Non-IE conditional comment like this:

```
<!--[if !IE]> -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="src/jquery.poshytip.js"></script>
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

The above code will be readable by all the browsers, except IE! And since that IE couldn't load the JS, it would throw the error which you got!